# If I restart compilation will it pick up where it left off?

Tags: haskell, makefile, ghc

I'm building GHC from source but forgot to add the -j3 option to tell it to use both cores on my machine.

If I <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> and restart the process, will it continue building from the current stage in the process, or will it start all over again?

Comment: Source files that have already been compiled will not be compiled again.

Comment: ...and I just discovered this myself because the install failed and gave me the opportunity to try again. I knew this was true for `make` with C/C++ files but I wasn't sure if the same was true when using GHC to compile a newer GHC. Thanks.

Comment: Right, GHC has a "make" mode which it uses by default.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Files that have been compiled will not be compiled again.

(sources: Tom's comment and personal experience)